How to debug segfault and mod_wsgi conda/mamba environments?
I have tried in vain to get core dumping and gdb to work, but cannot seem to get a core to dump or gdb to find the symbols it needs. So here's the gist of everything happening.
I have installed miniforge3. I have done mamba install mod_wsgi in the base environment to install mod_wsgi 5.0.0. I have two virtual hosts in Apache; I am creating a virtual environment for each virtual host with mamba create -n <name of env>. The sys.prefix is this:
/opt/miniforge3

Printing sys.path yields this:
['', '/opt/miniforge3/lib/python312.zip', '/opt/miniforge3/lib/python3.12', '/opt/miniforge3/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/opt/miniforge3/lib/python3.12/site-packages']

Running echo $PATH as root user yields this. Upon installation of miniforge3 as root, it appeared to add /opt/miniforge3/bin to the path automatically, but I still had to export it later by adding a file in /etc/profile.d so a non-privileged user would have it in their path, so now it appears twice when you're logged in as root. I don't know if that will cause issues or not:
/opt/miniforge3/bin:/opt/miniforge3/condabin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.0/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/opt/miniforge3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/cfengine/bin

In /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d I have a .conf file that loads the WSGI module like so:
<IfModule !wsgi_module>
    LoadModule wsgi_module /opt/miniforge3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py312.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
</IfModule>

Both virtual environments I have created have python 3.12.7 installed to match mod_wsgi.
My virtual hosts .conf file looks like this (edited to relevant parts):
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName domainNameOne.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domainNameOne"

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/domainNameOne-error.log"
  LogLevel info
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/domainNameOne-access.log" combined

  ## WSGI configuration
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess domainNameOne display-name=%{GROUP} home=/var/www/vhosts/domainNameOne python-home=/opt/miniforge3/envs/app1 threads=1 user=hydro
  WSGIProcessGroup domainNameOne
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vhosts/domainNameOne/wsgi.py"


  ## Anything start with dot
  <DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
     Require all denied
  </DirectoryMatch>

  <LocationMatch "\/\.">
     Require all denied
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location />
     Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName domainNameTwo.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo"

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/domainNameTwo-error.log"
  LogLevel info
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/domainNameTwo-access.log" combined

  ## WSGI configuration
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess domainNameTwo display-name=%{GROUP} home=/var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo python-home=/opt/miniforge3/envs/app2 threads=1 user=hydro
  WSGIProcessGroup domainNameTwo
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo/wsgi.py"

  ## Anything start with dot
  <DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">
     Require all denied
  </DirectoryMatch>

  <LocationMatch "\/\.">
     Require all denied
  </LocationMatch>

  <Location />
     Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

Apache's .conf:
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
LogLevel info

For the rest of this, I'll focus on just one of the applications since the errors I receive are the same between them. So, domainNameTwo WSGI script looks like this (I am running a Flask application using blueprints):
import sys
from api import create_app
from os import getcwd

sys.path.insert(0, getcwd() + "/api")
sys.path.append(getcwd() + "/api/models")

application = create_app()

Now, when I systemctl restart httpd, I go to domainNameTwo.com and receive a 500 error. In the apache's error_log I receive messages about segfaults on the WSGI app:
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.098111 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280203:tid 280203] mod_wsgi (pid=280203): Starting process 'domainNameOne' with uid=36143, gid=48 and threads=1.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.099092 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280204:tid 280204] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Starting process 'domainNameTwo' with uid=36143, gid=48 and threads=1.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.101579 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280203:tid 280203] mod_wsgi (pid=280203): Python home /opt/miniforge3/envs/app1.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.101656 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280203:tid 280203] mod_wsgi (pid=280203): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.101982 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280204:tid 280204] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Python home /opt/miniforge3/envs/app2.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.102046 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280204:tid 280204] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.102127 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 280200:tid 280200] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/3.0.7 mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.102145 2024] [mpm_event:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] AH00490: Server built: Aug  5 2024 00:00:00
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.102163 2024] [core:notice] [pid 280200:tid 280200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.106853 2024] [http2:info] [pid 280205:tid 280205] h2_workers: created with min=25 max=37 idle_ms=600000
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.107965 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280205:tid 280205] mod_wsgi (pid=280205): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.109002 2024] [http2:info] [pid 280207:tid 280207] h2_workers: created with min=25 max=37 idle_ms=600000
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.110156 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280207:tid 280207] mod_wsgi (pid=280207): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.120330 2024] [http2:info] [pid 280206:tid 280206] h2_workers: created with min=25 max=37 idle_ms=600000
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.121614 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280206:tid 280206] mod_wsgi (pid=280206): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.123846 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280207:tid 280207] mod_wsgi (pid=280207): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.138679 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280206:tid 280206] mod_wsgi (pid=280206): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.142589 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280205:tid 280205] mod_wsgi (pid=280205): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.143744 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280207:tid 280207] mod_wsgi (pid=280207): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.161980 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280205:tid 280205] mod_wsgi (pid=280205): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.163719 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280206:tid 280206] mod_wsgi (pid=280206): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.699499 2024] [core:notice] [pid 280200:tid 280200] AH00051: child pid 280204 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/httpd
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.699649 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Process 'domainNameTwo' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.699668 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Process 'domainNameTwo' terminated by signal 11
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.699690 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Process 'domainNameTwo' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.701459 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286088:tid 286088] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Starting process 'domainNameTwo' with uid=36143, gid=48 and threads=1.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.704146 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286088:tid 286088] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Python home /opt/miniforge3/envs/app2.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.704212 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286088:tid 286088] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Initializing Python.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.702656 2024] [core:notice] [pid 280200:tid 280200] AH00051: child pid 286088 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/httpd
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.702719 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Process 'domainNameTwo' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.702728 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Process 'domainNameTwo' terminated by signal 11
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.702735 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280200:tid 280200] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Process 'domainNameTwo' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.704057 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286103:tid 286103] mod_wsgi (pid=286103): Starting process 'domainNameTwo' with uid=36143, gid=48 and threads=1.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.706740 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286103:tid 286103] mod_wsgi (pid=286103): Python home /opt/miniforge3/envs/app2.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.706800 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286103:tid 286103] mod_wsgi (pid=286103): Initializing Python.

In the virtual host specific error log, I get this:
[Tue Oct 15 11:24:04.129726 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280204:tid 280204] mod_wsgi (pid=280204): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.275309 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 280204:tid 280304] [remote 10.159.64.61:53297] mod_wsgi (pid=280204, process='domainNameTwo', application=''): Loading Python script file '/var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.667099 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 280205:tid 280336] [client 10.159.64.61:53297] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'domainNameTwo': /var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo/wsgi.py
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:45.715999 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286088:tid 286088] mod_wsgi (pid=286088): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.145008 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286088:tid 286091] [remote 10.159.64.61:53298] mod_wsgi (pid=286088, process='domainNameTwo', application=''): Loading Python script file '/var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.509611 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 280206:tid 280359] [client 10.159.64.61:53298] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'domainNameTwo': /var/www/vhosts/domainNameTwo/wsgi.py, referer: https://domainNameTwo.com/
[Tue Oct 15 11:50:46.718194 2024] [wsgi:info] [pid 286103:tid 286103] mod_wsgi (pid=286103): Attach interpreter ''.

If I uninstall python packages that are related to SQL in some way (flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, geoalchemy2, etc), then I get messages about those modules not being found obviously, but I get no segfaults. I have tried setting header-buffer-size=131072 (quadruple the default value) in the WSGIDaemonProcess of each virtual host, but it doesn't fix the problem.
I am on RedHat and core dumping seems impossible for some reason. As root, I have set ulimit -c unlimited and have tried altering the proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern to many different things to get it to dump with no luck (I have it currently set back to the default which is |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h). When I use coredumpctl list, everything shows "none" even though coredump.conf is set to use the defaults:
[Coredump]
#Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=

I have tried uncommenting Storage=external to see if that would force it, but no luck.
coredumpctl info <pid> generates this:
           PID: 292401 (httpd)
           UID: 36143 (hydro)
           GID: 48 (apache)
        Signal: 11 (SEGV)
     Timestamp: Tue 2024-10-15 12:34:47 EDT (3min 56s ago)
  Command Line: $'(wsgi:domainNameT' -DFOREGROUND
    Executable: /usr/sbin/httpd
 Control Group: /system.slice/httpd.service
          Unit: httpd.service
         Slice: system.slice
       Boot ID: 98404b4ba09d4a7bbde55d9149e95df7
    Machine ID: 1788bfff64a44078829e9e7872ced29f
      Hostname: myHostName
       Storage: none
       Message: Process 292401 (httpd) of user 36143 dumped core.

Switching gears; when I try to employ gdb I mostly don't know what I'm looking at. I have tried to follow the directions for daemon processes, like this (as root):
gdb /usr/sbin/httpd <pid of domainNameTwo mod_wsgi app>

When it attached, I refresh domainNameTwo.com to get the 500 error and instead of the page refreshing and producing the error, it just hangs. I then put thread apply all bt as the documentation instructs and this is what I get:
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 10.2-13.el9
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...
Reading symbols from .gnu_debugdata for /usr/sbin/httpd...
(No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for /usr/sbin/httpd)
Attaching to program: /usr/sbin/httpd, process 292401
[New LWP 292583]
[New LWP 292584]
[New LWP 292585]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f2de1f019ff in poll () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install httpd-core-2.4.57-11.el9_4.1.x86_64
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f2ddf466640 (LWP 292585) "httpd"):
#0  0x00007f2de1f0e21e in epoll_wait () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2de21dd310 in impl_pollset_poll.lto_priv () from target:/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f2de10b4322 in wsgi_daemon_worker (thread=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:9019
#3  wsgi_daemon_thread (thd=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:9188
#4  0x00007f2de1e89c02 in start_thread () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f2de1f0ec40 in clone3 () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f2ddfc67640 (LWP 292584) "httpd"):
#0  0x00007f2de1f0422d in select () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2de21df849 in apr_sleep () from target:/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f2de10a49d3 in wsgi_deadlock_thread (thd=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:9228
#3  0x00007f2de1e89c02 in start_thread () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f2de1f0ec40 in clone3 () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f2de0468640 (LWP 292583) "httpd"):
#0  0x00007f2de1f0422d in select () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2de21df849 in apr_sleep () from target:/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f2de10a25cd in wsgi_monitor_thread (thd=<optimized out>, data=0x5601865bfca8) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:9510
#3  0x00007f2de1e89c02 in start_thread () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f2de1f0ec40 in clone3 () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f2de202e540 (LWP 292401) "httpd"):
#0  0x00007f2de1f019ff in poll () from target:/lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f2de21d7de1 in apr_poll () from target:/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f2de10b7821 in wsgi_daemon_main (daemon=0x5601865bfca8, p=0x5601863bec28) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:9811
#3  wsgi_start_process (p=p@entry=0x5601863bec28, daemon=0x5601865bfca8) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:10542
#4  0x00007f2de10b8d95 in wsgi_start_daemons (p=0x5601863bec28) at src/server/mod_wsgi.c:10780
#5  0x0000560185e8bced in ap_run_pre_mpm ()
#6  0x00007f2de1ad4695 in event_run () from target:/etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#7  0x0000560185e816d8 in ap_run_mpm ()
#8  0x0000560185e6f64f in main ()

I have tried to take care of the Missing separate debugInfos message by running the command it suggests, but that fails too in that no debugInfo things are found for httpd-core... package.
Can anyone help me either determine what is wrong in my mod_wsgi config that is causing the segfaults or help me figure out how to get debugging httpd processes or core dumps to work? I am at a total loss after investing many hours into this.

Update Three - mod_wsgi fix
My problem with mod_wsgi turned out to be that the virtual environment version of python had to match exactly the version of python that was in my base environment where I had installed the mod_wsgi package. So, to clarify, when I installed the miniforge3 distribution, the base environment had python 3.12.6 installed in it. I then installed mod_wsgi in the base environment so it compiled against this version of python. When I created my two virtual environments, I simply let it install the latest version of python by giving the general install command mamba install python (this is the same as conda install python for anyone using conda instead of mamba). By not specifying a specific python version, it ended up installing python 3.12.7. This caused a mismatch between the python version mod_wsgi was compiled against (3.12.6) and the versions in my virtual environments (3.12.7). Once I downgraded the python in my virtual environments to 3.12.6, everything began working.
Update Two - using gdb in active httpd process
I realized I missed a vital part of the command workflow found in the mod_wsgi debug techniques docs. I had to resume the debugger using cont before trying to use thread apply all bt. This became my full workflow:

Get the PID of the httpd process I wanted to attach to by finding the running process in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
Attach to it with gdb (gnu debugger): gdb /usr/sbin/httpd <pid>
Reproduce the error I was seeing on the site. For me, I just had to refresh the site I was trying to run. This would cause the page to hang because the debugger is active and it's waiting for you to resume!
Resume the debugger (gdb) cont
You should get some sort of error message now, like the Segementation Fault (11) message. After you receive that, you then do (gdb) thread apply all bt to get the backtrace. If you don't understand C, you won't really understand much about the backtrace, but thankfully the developer of mod_wsgi was able to help me there, check out his google mailing list.

Update One - fixing core dumps
I did at least get the core dumps to finally start working. The key was checking /var/log/messages on my system. There, it told me that Resource limits disable core dumping for process 358856 (httpd). So, after more googling around, I discovered I needed to update a couple files:
Everything hereforth I am doing as root.
In /etc/systemd/system.conf, I needed to set:
DefaultLimitCORE=infinity

Originally, that value was 0:infinity which I had mistaken to mean that there wasn't really a limit and it could be a size anywhere from 0 to infinity. Not so; that actually means core dumping is disabled. After saving that change, I had to reload the daemon:
systemctl daemon-reload

I then also needed to update the httpd service configuation. To do that:
systemctl edit httpd

The file should tell you the appropriate lines in which to put edits. I added the lines
[Service]
LimitCORE=infinity

I also checked to make sure my fs.suid_dumpable was equal to 2 in /etc/sysctl.conf. If you need to make changes here, don't forget to sysctl -p to apply them.
I also checked the location specified in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern was writable (I left it set as the default, seen in my OP above).
After these changes, I restarted the httpd service: systemctl restart httpd. This took a little bit, so just wait it out if you think it's hanging.
After the service restarts, get one of the PIDs you're trying to debug. I did this by looking at my apache error_log. You could also pgrep -l httpd and that will give you PIDs but not much information to know which PID is relevant to what process. You can then verify core dumps are enabled by running:
cat /proc/<httpd_pid>/limits | grep 'Max core file size'

It printed 'unlimited' for me. I do also have ulimit -c unlimited set for root.
After all that, I was able to refresh my problematic application page and the core dump file was created. Since my system uses systemd, I have the coredumpctl utility. Using coredumpctl info <httpd_pid> I could get some info about the process that segfaulted. Using coredumpctl debug <httpd_pid>, I could enter the gdb debugger with the core dump file and get an output like this:
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 10.2-13.el9
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd...
Reading symbols from .gnu_debugdata for /usr/sbin/httpd...
(No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for /usr/sbin/httpd)

warning: Can't open file /dev/zero (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing
[New LWP 495428]
[New LWP 495426]
[New LWP 495298]
[New LWP 495427]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `(wsgi:domainNameT -DFOREGROUND'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  PyObject_GetAttr (v=0x7f33d8560130, name=0x7f33daa33c20 <_PyRuntime+45280>) at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.12.6/Include/object.h:968
968 /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.12.6/Include/object.h: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f33d8f51640 (LWP 495428))]
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install httpd-core-2.4.57-11.el9_4.1.x86_64

You could enter another command into the debugger like bt or bt full to get more detailed backtrace of the error if you wanted.
